# Java : Compare previous record with current record in arraylist

Tags: java

I have a sorted array list with 6 elements.The first 5 elements have some value, and the 6th one is empty.

I want to loop through this ArrayList, and compare the first 5 elements of first record, with the same elements in next record. If any one of the element is different, then populate 6th element.

Anyone know an easier and faster approach to do that?

Thanks
Angad

Comment: add your attempts and we will help you

Answer (score 1):

First split the all records into many `String[]`, then parse all values in each. After that you can compare the current record with the first one. Here is an example:

```
public class StringComparison {

ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public void comapreStrings() {
    // The list you are comparing everything to
    String[] firstRecord = list.get(0);

    for(int n = 1; n < list.size(); n++) {
        String[] currentRecord = list.get(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRecord.length; i++) {
            String val1 = firstRecord[i];
            String val2 = currentRecord[i];
            if (val1.equals(val2)) {
                // The two strings are the same
            } else {
                // Replace "a value" with whatever you want to fill the 6th element with
                currentRecord[5] = "a value";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akash, But I have only one arraylist. I need to compare record by record. My requirement is to generate a sequence id whenever a new record is encountered.

Comment: What do you mean by record?

Comment: following is example of my Arraylist
Row1 : A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, ' '
Row2:  A1, B1, C1, D1, E2, ' '

I need to compare values in first row with values in the next. In the above case, since E1 != E2, It means it is differnt, so need to generate a sequence number, and populate the 6th element of array which is currently blank.

Comment: So is your ArrayList one with `String[]` or `String`?

Comment: thanks Akash, but i have hundreds of records, not just two.

Comment: Do you want to compare the first with all the other ones or the previous one with the one after it? If it's comparing the first with the rest, my edit is the answer.

Comment: compare with the next one. Basically, it is arraylist of array. Since the arraylist is already sorted, I need to compare the first five elements in the first array, with the same elements in the next. If they exactly match, it means I can assign the next array the same sequence id as first one, if not I will assign new sequence id. Then repeat the same for the next array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be an alternative to think about:

```
public String[] generateFirstRow(int startingRow) {

    final String[] row1 = rowList.get(startingRow);
    final String[] row2 = rowList.get(startingRow + 1);
    final List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(row1).collect(toList());
    final List<String> toAdd = Arrays.stream(row2).parallel().sorted().filter(s -> !list1.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (list1.get(list1.size() - 1) == "") {
        list1.set(list1.size() - 1, toAdd.get(0));
        return list1.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    return new String[0];

}
```

Now you can call this per row you have untill the pre-last one.